# I would like to grep all files except some file types?

Tags: grep

How do I recursively `grep` files within a given folders except a couple file types?

For example, I'm looking for a string within my workspace folder but it ends up searching inside sql files and generates serialized strings.

So in this case, I'd like to `grep` the workspace folder except sql files.

I'm preferably looking for a one-liner if possible.

Comment: Be aware that Linux and Unix and unix-a-likes don't really have "file types" in the way you seem to want. It's only by convention that file names have a ".c" or ".txt" or ".sql" suffix - those suffixes aren't even Windows-style "extensions", much less indicators that SQL or text or C source code live inside the files.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you have GNU `grep` you can use the `--exclude=GLOB` option, like

```
grep -r --exclude='*.sql' pattern dir/
```

Comment: How to exclude a single file?

Comment: @Nayeem, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204614/run-grep-excluding-a-file-in-a-specific-path

Answer (score 11):

This will do that for you and exclude .sql and .txt files:

```
find /some/dir -type f ! -name '*\.sql' ! -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'foobar'
```

However it sounds like [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) would be a far better tool for what you're trying to do:

```
ack -a --nosql 'foobar' /some/dir
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the 'ack' part and put it in my answer, which is now deleted.

Comment: Another user [notes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7800) that `ack - a --nobinary` includes binary files

Comment: The backslash in the filename pattern is not needed.