# Run `grep` excluding a file in a specific path

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to exclude the file `./test/main.cpp` from my search.

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
$ grep -r pattern --exclude=./test/main.cpp
./test/main.cpp:pattern
./lib/main.cpp:pattern
./src/main.cpp:pattern
```

I know it is possible to get the output that I want by using multiple commands in a pipes-and-filters arrangement, but is there some quoting/escaping that will make `grep` understand what I want natively?

Comment: A solution based on filtering the output doesn't scale well because it needlessly searches the file before excluding the associated results.  The issue is magnified if I want to exclude entire directories (with `--exclude-dir`).  That's why I would like to make grep perform the exclusion natively.

Comment: --exclude specifies glob not a path

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`grep` can't do this for file in one certain directory if you have more files with the same name in different directories, use find instead:

`find . -type f \! -path './test/main.cpp' -exec grep pattern {} \+`

Comment: Why are you escaping `\!` and `\+`?  It seems to work fine without the backslashes.

Comment: @nobar I'm used to it because some characters are shell keywords so you'll never be surprised because nothing can happen if they are escaped.

Comment: "`grep` can't do this, use `find` instead" -- perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible with GNU `grep`. You don't need pipes though.

With `find`:

```
find . ! -path ./test/main.cpp -type f -exec grep pattern {} +
```

With `zsh`:

```
grep pattern ./**/*~./test/main.cpp(.)
```

(excludes hidden files, just as well to exclude the .git, .svn...).

Answer (score 3):

I could write a book : "The lost art of `xargs`". The `find ... -exec … ';` launches a grep for each file (but the variant with `-exec … +` doesn't). Well, we're wasting CPU cycles these days so why not, right? But if performance and memory and power is an issue: use xargs:

```
find . -type f \! -path 'EXCLUDE-FILE' -print0 | xargs -r0 grep 'PATTERN'
```

GNU's `find`'s `-print0` will `NUL`-terminate its output and `xargs`' `-0` option honors that format as input. This ensures whatever funny characters your file has, the pipeline won't get confused. The `-r` option makes sure there's no error in case `find` finds nothing.

Note, you can now do things like:

```
find . -type f -print0 | grep -z -v "FILENAME EXCLUDE PATTERN" | 
  xargs -r0 grep 'PATTERN'
```

GNU grep's `-z` does the same thing as xargs' `-0`.

Comment: Some interesting notes, but I'm not sure you're correct about the performance issue.  As I understand it `find -exec (cmd) {} +` works the same as `xargs` and `find -exec (cmd) {} \;` works the same as `xargs -n1`.  In other words, your statement is only correct if the `\;` version is used.

Comment: Piping into `xargs` is less efficient than using `-exec … +` (albeit marginally). None of the answers here even mention `-exec … \;`.

Comment: Well, s--t. I date myself. Thanks for the comments and corrections. I thought the \+ was a typo. Oh look, `-exec ... +` added in Jan 2005. Yeah, I'm not out of date ... at ... all.

Answer (score 2):

If your `find` supports `-path` which was added to POSIX in 2008 but still missing in Solaris:

```
find . ! -path ./test/main.cpp -type f -exec grep pattern /dev/null {} +
```

Comment: I don't think that will work becuase nobar wants main.cpp in other directories

Comment: won't your pattern exclude main.cpp from all the other directories too?  That would not be desirable

Comment: @EricRenouf: Oh, my mistake, a mis-reading. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Gilles: Why `-path` is not POSIX?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake, it's been added in 2008. Still missing from Solaris though.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for the information, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here's the approach that I prefer:

```
grep pattern $(find . -type f ! -path './test/main.cpp')
```

By keeping the `grep` at the beginning of the command, I think this is a little more clear -- plus it doesn't disable `grep`'s color highlighting.  In a sense, using `find` in a command-substitution is just a way of extending/replacing the (limited) file-search subset of `grep`'s functionality.

---

To me, the [`find -exec` syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec) is kind of arcane.  One complexity with `find -exec` is the (sometimes) need for escaping various characters (notably if `\;` is used under Bash).  Just for the purposes of putting things into familiar contexts, the following two commands are basically equivalent:

```
find . ! -path ./test/main.cpp -type f -exec grep pattern {} +
find . ! -path ./test/main.cpp -type f -print0 |xargs -0 grep pattern
```

---

If you want to **exclude subdirectories**, it may be necessary to use a wildcard.  I don't fully understand the schema here -- [talk about arcane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command):

```
grep pattern $(find . -type f ! -path './test/main.cpp' ! -path './lib/*' )
```

---

One further note to generalize `find`-based solutions **for use in scripts**: The `grep` command-line should include the `-H`/`--with-filename` option.  Otherwise it will change the output formatting under the circumstance that there happens to be only one filename in the search results from `find`.  This is notable because it doesn't appear to be necessary if using `grep`'s native file-search (with the `-r` option).

...Even better, though, is to include `/dev/null` as a first file to search.  This solves two problems:

- It ensures that if there is one file to search, `grep` will think there are two and use the multiple-file output mode.
- It ensures that if there are no files to search, `grep` will think there is one file and not hang waiting on stdin.

So the final answer is:

```
grep pattern /dev/null $(find . -type f ! -path './test/main.cpp')
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the output of `find` in a command substitution. This breaks if there are file names containing spaces or other special characters. Use `find -exec`, it's robust and easy to use.

Comment: @Gilles: Very good point -- also the output could possibly exceed the command-line size limits of some programs.  Caveat emptor.

Comment: Ugh.  'find' syntax is terribly difficult.  '-o' is an "or" operator (also '-or' on Linux), but it's typical usage (for example with '-prune') doesn't map conceptually to the notion of a logical or.  It's a functional or rather than logical or.

Comment: Another way to exclude subdirectories based on matching a name: `find -iname "*target*" -or -name 'exclude' -prune`.  Well, it sort of works -- the pruned directory will be listed, but not searched.  If you don't want it listed, you can append a sort of redundant `! -name 'exclude'`